# Perl: $SIG{__DIE__}, eval { } and stack trace

Tags: perl, eval, stack-trace

I have a piece of Perl code somewhat like the following (strongly simplified): There are some levels of nested subroutine calls (actually, methods), and some of the inner ones do their own exception handling:

```
sub outer { middle() }

sub middle {
    eval { inner() };
    if ( my $x = $@ ) { # caught exception
        if (ref $x eq 'ARRAY') {
            print "we can handle this ...";
        }
        else {
            die $x; # rethrow
        }
    }
}

sub inner { die "OH NOES!" }
```

Now I want to change that code so that it does the following:

- print a full stack trace for every exception that "bubbles up" all the way to the outermost level (`sub outer`). Specifically, the stack trace should **not** stop at the first level of "`eval { }`".
- Not having to change the the implementation of any of the inner levels.

Right now, the way I do this is to install a localized `__DIE__` handler inside the `outer` sub:

```
use Devel::StackTrace;

sub outer {
    local $SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
        my $error = shift;
        my $trace = Devel::StackTrace->new;
        print "Error: $error\n",
              "Stack Trace:\n",
              $trace->as_string;
    };
    middle();
}
```

[**EDIT**: I made a mistake, the code above actually *doesn't* work the way I want, it actually bypasses the exception handling of the `middle` sub. So I guess the question should really be: Is the behaviour I want even possible?]

<del>This works perfectly</del>, the only problem is that, if I understand the docs correctly, it relies on behaviour that is explicitly deprecated, namely the fact that `__DIE__` handlers are triggered even for "`die`"s inside of "`eval { }`"s, which they really shouldn't. Both `perlvar` and `perlsub` state that this behaviour might be removed in future versions of Perl.

Is there another way I can achieve this without relying on deprecated behaviour, or is it save to rely on even if the docs say otherwise?

Comment: There's a similar discussion available here: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=799791 - it comes down to `local $SIG{__DIE__} = \&Carp::confess;` basically, but has some additional analysis.

Comment: Still useful 13 years later! 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is *not* safe to rely on anything that the documentation says is deprecated. The behavior could (and likely will) change in a future release. Relying on deprecated behavior locks you into the version of Perl you're running today.

Unfortunately, I don't see a way around this that meets your criteria. The "right" solution is to modify the inner methods to call `Carp::confess` instead of `die` and drop the custom `$SIG{__DIE__}` handler.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp qw'confess';

outer();

sub outer { middle(@_) }

sub middle { eval { inner() }; die $@ if $@ }

sub inner { confess("OH NOES!") }
__END__
OH NOES! at c:\temp\foo.pl line 11
    main::inner() called at c:\temp\foo.pl line 9
    eval {...} called at c:\temp\foo.pl line 9
    main::middle() called at c:\temp\foo.pl line 7
    main::outer() called at c:\temp\foo.pl line 5
```

Since you're dieing anyway, you may not need to trap the call to `inner()`. (You don't in your example, your actual code may differ.)

In your example you're trying to return data via `$@`. You can't do that. Use

```
my $x = eval { inner(@_) };
```

instead. (I'm assuming this is just an error in simplifying the code enough to post it here.)

Comment: Right, but I was hoping I could catch unforeseen errors with this (some of the inner levels might not be written by me). I'm beginning to think that the behaviour I want is actually not possible (See my edit of the question).

Comment: I understand and sympathize. Doing this externally requires dark magic. Sinan's answer is a good one if you can stomach overriding built-in functions. I'd have no qualms about doing so for debugging but would be hesitant to use it in production code. I *might* use it in a script but would *not* use it in a module.

Comment: "In your example you're trying to return data via $@. You can't do that."  Well, yes you can.  Returning data is a bad idea (and is not what the OP is doing), but you can throw extra information about the exception.  It is common to throw instances of classes and pattern-match on their type, for example.  (I recommend the TryCatch module on CPAN, for extra syntax sugar in this case, however.)

Comment: To clarify: the "deprecated" behavior is the oddity of $SIG{__DIE__} that it will catch exceptions thrown inside eval blocks.  http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html states that "this behavior may be changed in a future release".

Answer (score 11):

**UPDATE:** I changed the code to override `die` globally so that exceptions from other packages can be caught as well.

Does the following do what you want?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Devel::StackTrace;

use ex::override GLOBAL_die => sub {
    local *__ANON__ = "custom_die";
    warn (
        'Error: ', @_, "\n",
        "Stack trace:\n",
        Devel::StackTrace->new(no_refs => 1)->as_string, "\n",
    );
    exit 1;
};

use M; # dummy module to functions dying in other modules

outer();

sub outer {
    middle( @_ );
    M::n(); # M::n dies
}

sub middle {
    eval { inner(@_) };
    if ( my $x = $@ ) { # caught exception
        if (ref $x eq 'ARRAY') {
            print "we can handle this ...";
        }
        else {
            die $x; # rethrow
        }
    }
}

sub inner { die "OH NOES!" }
```

Comment: Hm, interesting. This actually does exactly what I had in mind. It also shows that I probably should rethingk my general approach. I don't really want to go so far as to override builtins. :(

Comment: I think you have to choose between changing inner() and changing what die() means.

Comment: note that some other packages, such as XML::Simple will die and catch it with an eval, and that you will be reporting these events. (XML::Simple does this when XML::SAX is not installed and falls back to another parser)

Answer (score 4):

Note that overriding `die` will only catch actual calls to `die`, *not* Perl errors like dereferencing `undef`.

I don't think the general case is possible; the entire point of `eval` is to consume errors.  You MIGHT be able to rely on the deprecated behavior for exactly this reason: there's no other way to do this at the moment.  But I can't find any reasonable way to get a stack trace in every case without potentially breaking whatever error-handling code already exists however far down the stack.