# Catching errors with both mod_cgi & mod_perl

Tags: perl, error-handling, mod-perl

Thanks to everyone in advance.

I've been doing some research on error handling and I don't feel like I'm getting a solid understanding of what I should do.

Preamble: My code is living in Apache and executed in the browser, my goals don't include command line execution.

I'd like to have the behavior of CGI::Carp (fatalsToBrowser) with the ability to capture the output and be able to throw it in my own templated page, email it etc... I did notice that fatalsToBrowser doesn't work with mod_perl. Does anyone know why? How is Apache/mod_perl getting in the way?

---

First Goal: I'd like to put something together that works if the code is being executed with mod_perl or mod_cgi.

Second Goal: I'd like to have a high-level method(s) that catches all the errors similar to .NET's Application_Error (in global.asax) and PHP's set_exception_handler()  and set_error_handler() methods. These allow you to take control when an error is raised, without wrapping code in messy<strike>/gross</strike> try-catch statements.

---

Things I've read/reviewed:

1.) [OO Exception Handling in Perl](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2002/11/14/exception.html), but wasn't what I was looking for. Most of the stuff I want to catch is die()ing. The next link also says that this article is out of date and deprecated.

2.) [Perl: $SIG{__DIE__}, eval { } and stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971273/perl-sigdie-eval-and-stack-trace), but I didn't get much from this related to my goals.

3.) Practical Mode Perl (O'Reilly), Chapter 21 "Error Handling and Debugging". Thankfully all my perl code uses strict and warnings are enabled, and most important things mentioned in Chapter 6 "Coding with mod_perl in Mind" are already done.

4.) I've dug through the tables of contents in "Learning Perl", "Perl Cookbook", "Programming Perl" and "Higher Order Perl" and didn't see anything that stuck out at me. If you think I missed something there please let me know. :)

---

I don't remember where (maybe in "Practical mod_perl", but I've read that you should not mess with $SIG{__DIE__}.

Comment: Are your scripts real `mod_perl` scripts or are you just running CGI scripts as `ModPerl::Registry` scripts for the performance advantage?

Comment: My scripts will (should) perform the same in either environment.

Comment: I think you should re-evaluate your opinion on try/catch blocks. They are not at all messy or gross if used at the right level.

Comment: @Manni, I use try/catch blocks like that in other code... like I said in my OP, the second goal is "high-level" trapping. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the `mod_perl` website's bit on [Alternative Exception Handling Techniques](http://perl.apache.org/docs/general/perl_reference/perl_reference.html#Alternative_Exception_Handling_Techniques)?  It discusses about how you can catch uncaught exceptions though the use of overriding the global `die()` function instead of using `$SIG{__DIE__}`.  A much cleaner method but not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

What type of errors are you trying to catch? Are [custom error pages](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html) not sufficient for your purposes?

My CGI scripts are short (OK, this is really bare bones — and *untested*):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use My::App;
use My::ErrorReporter qw( error_to_html );

run();

sub run {
    my $app = eval {
        My::App->new(
            'some_param',
            'another_param',
        )
    };

    unless ( $app ) {
        print error_to_html( $@ );
        return;
    }

    eval {
        $app->handle_request;        
    } and return;

    print error_to_html( $@ );
    return;
}

__END__
```

Now, `fatalsToBrowser` is not for your users. That is a development aid for you. The error messages users see should not convey information about the program. So, for example, in a routine that opens and reads a configuration file, you should do something like:

```
sub read_my_config {
    my $self = shift;

    open my $config_h, '<', $self->config_file;

    unless ( $config_h ) {
        # This goes to the Apache error log where you can read it
        warn sprintf(
            "Cannot open '%s': %s", 
            $self->config_file, $!
        );
        # This is for web site visitors to see
        die "Cannot open configuration file";
    }

    # rest of the code
}
```

Comment: I allow the programmer to choose if they want the stackstrace shown in the error message... obviously in the production envirnment we would turn off the stack trace being shown. However I'd still like to have access to it so I can show the user a friendly message and email the administrator the real stacktrace or log it to the db etc... Please see my second goal in my OP, I don't want everything wrapped in a try/catch... I need a high level error catcher that can take control from their with thei appropriate information.

Comment: Does this look messy/gross to you?

Comment: Yes/No... I think @Weegee gave me what I was looking for. I need something not connected to the script(s) for global error trapping in my applications. I'm gonna see if that works before choosing an answer. Again thanks for your replies, much appreciated.