# Perl / Apache / CGI / Carp : Cannot get fatalsToBrowser to work

Tags: apache, perl, web-applications, cgi, carp

I am writing a perl web application running with apache and want to redirect error messages to the browser for debugging. For this, I found `fatalsToBrowser` from `CGI::Carp`.

Unfortunately, I still get an 'Internal Server Error' instead of the error message, which still ends up in the apache error log. Here is my code:

```
package Test;
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use Apache2::Request;

sub handler {
    my $request = Apache2::Request->new(shift);
    die("This is an error");
    print "here\n";
    return 1;
}

1;
```

In the documentation of [CGI::Carp](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI%3a%3aCarp) I read "Note that fatalsToBrowser may not work well with mod_perl version 2.0 and higher."

I am using mod_perl 2 and if I use `fatalsToBrowser` in a simple 'Hello World' cgi example, it works. But I am not sure if this function would not work in my setting or if I am doing something wrong.

Does anyone have an idea how to get this to work (maybe also with alternatives to CGI::Carp)?

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174463/catching-errors-with-both-mod-cgi-mod-perl

Comment: Does placing `local $SIG{__DIE__} = \&CGI::Carp::die;` in `handler` help?

Comment: A possibility is that the exception handler overrides the custom message handler CGI::Carp sets up.

Comment: Does `$ENV{MOD_PERL}` exists?

Comment: @ikegami: `$ENV{MOD_PERL}` is mod_perl/2.0.5. When I place the `$SIG{__DIE__}` in Handler, but it still gives me an 'internal server error'.

Comment: If I overwrite `$SIG{__DIE__} = sub { print "<h1>Error</h1>", $_[0]; exit();};`, I get the error message in the browser and my small example works, however, in my larger applications there can be exceptions, some are caught by `$SIG{__DIE__}` and some not...