# How can I get a traceback in Perl?

Tags: perl, exit, traceback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I force a stack backtrace for all fatal errors in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738628/how-do-i-force-a-stack-backtrace-for-all-fatal-errors-in-perl)

One of the things I like about Python, is that when a script exits because of an error, it spits out a traceback. I'm wondering is there anyway of getting a Perl to do this as well?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738628 . Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877638 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971273

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add this to the top of your script:

```
use Carp 'verbose';
$SIG{ __DIE__ } = sub { Carp::confess( @_ ) };
```

It will create a stack trace on all fatal errors.

Comment: You could also make that `$SIG{__DIE__} = \&Carp::confess;`

Comment: This answer really is much better than at the question that is considered a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 12):

Investigate the [Carp::Always](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Carp-Always) module.

Comment: `Carp::Always` is a much better method than messing about with sigdie because you can enable it from the command line.  `perl -MCarp::Always my_script`  Very, very nice.

Comment: I put `#!/c/Perl/bin/perl -MCarp::Always -w` as the first line in the script. And it said `Too late for "-MCarp::Always" option at ... line 1.`